# Copy amazon s3 bucket folder to local

Tags: python, amazon-s3, s3-bucket

I have this link:

```
s3://some_path/200_files/*.gz
```

I have the corresponding **ACCESS ID** and **SECRET KEY**. How to copy the complete folder (**200_files**) OR all the `.gz` to the local system? *Ubuntu CLI* or *Python* based solution. I understand that this is not a up to the mark question, answers in comments would work. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To copy all objects in an S3 bucket to your local machine simply use the aws `s3 cp` command with the `--recursive` option.

See: http://bigdatums.net/2016/09/04/copy-all-files-in-s3-bucket-to-local-with-aws-cli/

To set the credentials:

```
mkdir ~/.aws
touch credentials
```

**~/.aws/credentials** (sample content)

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
aws_secret_access_key=wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
```

More config [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-config-files.html)

Comment: Thanks. I had already gone through that link, I just thought that is meant for AWS shell, within the cloud. Should work, will let you know.

Comment: How do I include credentials? Do I need to set them as environment variables?

Comment: You need to configure you AWS client. Instructions here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-config-files.html Environment variables are also an option (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-environment.html)

Comment: Thanks. For those who follow up with this link, you need to manually create **~/.aws** directory and the **credentials** file within it, with the given content in the link.